# How to add different ID on same CLASS name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, frontend

What I would like to accomplish. I have a checklist in a website, and I want to add one more on button click (similar like in trello card). Because it is a lot of htlm I would like to add it from external html file. But I want different ID with each addition. Every id should look like id name and number.

Hope it is clear.

Here is the code:

```
$('.new-checklist').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.get('new-chk.html',function(data) {
    $('.checklist').append(data);
    $('.checklist-all').attr("id", "chk");
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Why do the checkboxes need IDs in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the anonymous function available to the `attr()` method to modify the attribute:

```
$('.checklist-all').attr("id", function(i){
  // 'i' : the index of the current element of
  // of the collection over which the method
  // iterates:

  // here we return the string 'chk' concatenated
  // with the index:
  return 'chk' + i;
});
```

Although to set the `id` I'd personally prefer to use `prop()`, but there's no real difference in practice. That said, though, I'd echo [Barmar's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39068407/how-to-add-different-id-on-same-class-name/39068768#comment65485657_39068407) to the question:

> Why do the checkboxes need IDs in the first place?

References:

- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Comment: Thank You all!, specially David. I need to create a multiple checklists as a html template which have some buttons and then be able to target only exact button which is pressed because they all have same functionality. What I was intent to do is to separate those buttons by parent ID name. Actually I messed up with my logic in the first place, I need to figure out different solution. But really thank you all for answers it will be useful in the future for myself or fellow coders ;)

Answer (score 1):

For what you are trying to do you should try a different selector like by position, rather than CLASS, since this would select all the elements of that class and not just the one you want.
Since you use `.append` to add the new check, then you know it is the last one so you can do:

```
$('.checklist').children().last().attr("id", "chk");
```

Your code should be:

```js
    $('.new-checklist').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $.get('new-chk.html',function(data) {
        $('.checklist').append(data);
        $('.checklist').children().last().attr("id", "{NEW_ID}");
      });
      return false;
    });
```

Also you it's ok to have the html in an external file but you should load it just once, instead of doing a request each time you want to add a new check.